# Orientation event (Jquery Mobile) show "Uncaught ReferenceError: css is not defined"

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling

I'm building a simple site with Bootstrap 3, in the first page I've an full width header with Bootstrap Carousel that show three images.
When viewport width is < 992px I wrote a media query that loads some picture and when width is > 992 its charges another. ok, simple, here's the HTML and CSS code for this.

```
<!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<header id="carousel-intro" class="carousel slide page-scroll ">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-intro" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-intro" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-intro" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner wow bounceIn" data-wow-duration="2s">
        <div class="item active">
            <div id="carousel-intro-img-1" class="fill"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div id="carousel-intro-img-2" class="fill"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div id="carousel-intro-img-3" class="fill"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-intro" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-intro" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

    <a id="scroll-link" class="page-scroll " href="#chi">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down white animated infinite pulse"></i>
    </a>
</header>
```

```css
/*Header section*/
.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel-indicators{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.icon-prev,.icon-next{
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*Setting carousel image*/
@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
    #carousel-intro-img-1{
        background-image:url(../img/intro-tablet/intro1g.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #carousel-intro-img-2{
        background-image:url(../img/intro-tablet/intro2g.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #carousel-intro-img-3{
        background-image:url(../img/intro-tablet/intro3g.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
    #carousel-intro-img-1{
        background-image:url(../img/intro-desktop/intro1g.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #carousel-intro-img-2{
        background-image:url(../img/intro-desktop/intro2g.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #carousel-intro-img-3{
        background-image:url(../img/intro-desktop/intro3g.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Ok, now I need to load the set of images used for w > 992 when the orientation of the device switches to landscape view, so I include custom jquery mobile:

```
script src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
```

and wrote this:

```
 $(window).bind('orientationchange resize', function(event){
  if(event.orientation) {
        if(event.orientation == 'portrait') {
             $('#carousel-intro-img-1'),css('background-image', 'url(../img/intro-tablet/intro1g.jpg)');
             $('#carousel-intro-img-2'),css('background-image', 'url(../img/intro-tablet/intro2g.jpg)');
             $('#carousel-intro-img-3'),css('background-image', 'url(../img/intro-tablet/intro3g.jpg)');
          } else 
        if (event.orientation == 'landscape') {
            $('#carousel-intro-img-1'),css('background-image', 'url(../img/intro-tablet-landscape/intro1g.jpg)');
            $('#carousel-intro-img-2'),css('background-image', 'url(../img/intro-tablet-landscape/intro2g.jpg)');
            $('#carousel-intro-img-3'),css('background-image', 'url(../img/intro-tablet-landscape/intro3g.jpg)');
          } 
        }  //event orientation
        else {}
  });
```

A strange thing happens, (I use Chrome Web Developer tool to test) the above approach works well for all the dimensions of the viewport> 768px, but not for the lower.

Why?

Analyzing the Chrome log console I get the following error:
  **Uncaught ReferenceError: css is not defined**

but it will not be still problems when w > = 768px because everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript, change

```
$('#carousel-intro-img-1'),css
```

to

```
$('#carousel-intro-img-1').css
```

in all instances (note the period instead of comma).

Comment: Oh god, I'm really tired this evening. Thanks

Comment: Error is in "url(../img/intro-tablet/intro1g.jpg)", I modify "url(img/intro-tablet/intro1g.jpg)" and it's ok. Thanks